# .htaccess multi URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profil.php?upime=$1
```

and it is working. Now I want to know how to rewrite the URL of another page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profil.php?upime=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ novica.php?nid=$2 - I did this, but is not working.
```

what can I do that I will have both rules in one `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do it like in your example as you are rewriting everything: `^(.*)$`.

If you want two different rules, you would need to select what urls you want to write to what end destination.

An example where you rewrite different urls that start with different strings to different destinations:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^starts_with_this(.*)$ profil.php?upime=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^starts_with_something_else(.*)$ novica.php?nid=$1
```

Comment: but what i must to write there where you wrote starts_with_this and starts_with_something_else?

Comment: @user1726756 That depends on what you want your urls to look like, could be `profil/` and `novica/` for example. By the way, you could end with a third rule that rewrites everything else that has not been rewritten yet.

Comment: but wait - if i write for example `profil/` and `novica/`, than my css design is not working - do i need to create a folders `profil/` and `novica/` and than copy the design inside?

Comment: @user1726756 There are different ways, but I always use absolute paths for my assets (images, css, js) to avoid that problem.

Comment: @user1726756 You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.